# PHP load page that link is set to

Tags: php, html

I have a small piece of PHP running that I am trying to get to load the page that the navigation links set.

So far it loads the home page fine, but that is set as the default. As soon as you click one of the other links it is not able to find the page.

So far my index.php page looks something like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <?php 
                // INCLUDING HEADER ON ALL PAGES
                include("pages/header.php");
            ?>

            <main> <!-- wrapping main tag !-->
            <?php 
                $pageLoaded = array('home', 'header' , 'about' , 'work'); // LIST ALL PAGES

                $page = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';

                if ( in_array($page, $pageLoaded) ){
                    include("pages/$page.php");
                } 

                // else {
                //     include("pages/404.php");
                // }
            ?>
            </main>

            <?php 
                // INCLUDING FOOTER ON ALL PAGES
                include("pages/footer.php");
            ?>
        </div>
```

The actual links in my header.php look like this

```
    <li><a href="home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="work">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
```

I am very new to PHP so not entirely sure how to get that if statement working correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_GET is populated from get variables (variables that appear after ?) so you would need to change your links to /index.php?page={page name}

```
<li><a href="/index.php?page=home">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?page=work">WORK</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?page=about">ABOUT</a></li>
```

Comment: That still retuns an object not found error. "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Removed the / by index. Seemed to do the trick! Thanks for simple solution

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to do that (include a file based only on internet parameter). There a risk on any person, include any file of the system inside your script. Try to make some validations on the parameters where page is requested.

Comment: It checks it against a whitelist so I don't see why this would be an issue